# Link non-registered user comments to main SE profile for migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, migration

In [this migrated question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/why-deshaken-video-looks-wobbly-and-how-to-fix-it), user MichaelT [left a comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/58037/why-deshaken-video-looks-wobbly-and-how-to-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment101136_58037) before the migration.

Since the user doesn't have a profile in the site the question was migrated to, there is [no profile linked to from the comment](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/why-deshaken-video-looks-wobbly-and-how-to-fix-it#comment17128_13454).

I would like to suggest linking to the user's main SE profile instead of just nothing.

I'm not sure if the same behavior occurs for answers left on questions before migration, but if it does, then I would suggest the same policy.

Comment: There are probably going to be complications with deleted accounts.  What if I deleted my account on the target site because I don't want to participate in that site anymore.  This opens me up to being pinged or being involved in a site that I left.  As long as deletion takes priority, this seems like a reasonable idea.

Comment: @psubsee2003 This isn't already an occurring with the unlinked text of the user's name?

Comment: correct, but what if MichaelT was a former user on Video.SE and doesn't want to be at all involved in the site anymore.  This sort of pulls him back into the site.  Your idea doesn't automatically create an account, but does create a path to connect a specific user back to the site

Comment: @psubsee2003 Right, but so does the plain text, depending on how many users choose the same handle. Yours is [easy to find](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=psubsee2003).

Comment: Of course.... it's a small issue, not a show stopper.  But if I had a major falling out with a specific site, I might not want to be easily reachable.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, you are, for anyone who comes across a migrated question. (o; Maybe post a request on that issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm on the fence with this. I can see reasons for it to work each way.

First off note the difference between having a post (or comment on a post) migrated to another site where one doesn't have an account and having a post on a site and later either dissociating the account or deleting it.  The disassociation and deletion will anonymize the user.

If I was a former user on Video.SE (deleted account because of all the evil mods there - now all my positively voted posts and comments are user1234) and had a post migrated from Photo.SE to Video.SE it would show up as MichaelT rather than user1234 currently.

In light of this, having the user name link to the network profile rather than not be a link isn't a "I don't want to be easily reachable" aspect. This isn't a problem.

What is a problem is the astonishment principle and confusion as to why my name goes to the network profile rather than the site profile (like everyone else's).  I suspect that would cause more support headaches than the no link currently does.